# Merge txt from a directory

Tags: c

How does one write a C program in Linux to read all text files (that is, files that end with .txt) in the current  directory and to merge them all into one text file and returns a file descriptor for the  new file.

Comment: Consider dirent.h

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Well I know how to write everything else, but a program that *returns* a file descriptor for the new file doesn't sound something that would be easy to achieve in Linux...

Comment: You're on Linux, so POSIX [`scandir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scandir.html) should be available to you.  That'll allow you to get the list of files to be concatenated.  Building a new file name requires a modicum of care.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask]  pages soon, and also about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You've not shown any effort to produce some code.  We'll help you fix problems in code you've tried to write, but we won't generally write your code for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can run commands on C code ( system(cmd) ).

First write a command which concatenates all the txt file in a txt :

```
 find . -name '*.txt' | xargs cat >> out.txt
```

Then call this command in c code. 
Then try to open out.txt.

Comment: I hope you've got a BIG disk, because `cat` will add the content of `out.txt` to `out.txt`, which takes a long time because `out.txt` is growing as it is being read from. (You might get away with it if all the other text files appear after `out.txt` in the output from `find`, or possibly if they're so small that buffering means that `out.txt` does not grow until after it has been processed.)